# Javascript undefined as property *name*

Tags: javascript

[Apparently](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0596517742), no objects in javascript can have *undefined* as the property **name** but you can hit F12 and pop this line in and it's fine :

```
var test = { undefined:10, 'b':12 }
```

What gives ?

Comment: Can you be more specific than paraphrasing a claim from a book and not even giving a page reference?

Comment: Old IE won't like that, but ES5 opened up key names like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `undefined` for property keys as well as unquoted strings.

If you type in `var test = { undefined:10, 'b':12 }`, `undefined` will be returned because of the use of the `var` keyword. However, if you type in the variable `test` in the console after that, you will see the returned object.

```
{"b": 12, "undefined": 10}
```

Then if you call `test["undefined"]`, the value `10` will be returned.

The property names get automatically converted to strings upon initialization.